# Sencha sdk build not include some classes

Tags: extjs, build, sdk, production-environment

i try migrate a developement environment to production with SDK Sencha tool.

But the proccess of building exclude of the "app-all.js" all models and stores defined in my App folder.

Only loads views and controllers. Any ideas why does this happen ?

Regards !.

**Edit form more info:**

For example mi cocina.js works as an app.js:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled : true,
    paths: {
        Ext: 'vendor/ext/src',
        My: 'app'
    } 
});

Ext.application({

   name: 'Alnitak',
   appFolder: 'app',


   controllers: ['Env','Cocina'],
   launch: function(){
     ...
   }
});
```

An the cocina controller:

```
Ext.define('Alnitak.controller.Cocina', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    store: [
        'PlatosArmados',
        'Niveles',
        'Submenues',
        'AlumnosPlato'
    ],
    model: [
        'PlatoArmado',
        'Nivel',
        'Submenu',
        'AlumnoPlato'
    ],
    views: [
        'grid.PlatoArmado',
        'grid.AlumnoPlato'
    ],
    init: function() { ...}
});
```

What i have modify ?

Comment: Does it work when you reference the classes in "requires" or "uses" properties, e.g. in Application.js (see template scaffolding)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean Sencha Command and not SDK, you have to change a few things:

1. Specify all your js paths in .sencha/app/sencha.cfg (parent folder is enough)
2. Build a new template app (http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/) and follow the pattern, not the Sencha Architect pattern for the Loader you use above. Sencha Cmd has its own way of handling javascript loading. You would not need to specify the paths with `Ext.Loader.setConfig()`

[If you want to use the Architect pattern though, here's the guide.](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?246508-Setting-up-your-Architect-Touch-projects-to-be-used-with-Sencha-Cmd-v3&p=901360)